# Why does my loop return an empty list error when I pass it a copied list, but does not error with an original list?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, slice, empty-list

```
short_texts = ['I like the apple', 'I like the orange as well', 'Finally, I like the inside of a kiwi the best']
sent_messages = []


def send_messages(messages):
    
    while messages:
        popped_st = short_texts.pop(0)
        print(popped_st)
        sent_messages.append(popped_st)


send_messages(short_texts[:])

print(short_texts)
print(sent_messages)
```

Error>

```
I like the apple
    I like the orange as well
    Finally, I like the inside of a kiwi the best
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Steve\Documents\python_work\8.11.py", line 13, in <module>
        send_messages(short_texts[:])
      File "C:\Users\Steve\Documents\python_work\8.11.py", line 8, in send_messages
        popped_st = short_texts.pop(0)
    IndexError: pop from empty list
    [Finished in 200ms]
```

If I get rid of the slice argument of the function call, the program works. Adding the slice, causes the "pop from empty list".

I am reading Python Crash Course, 2E, and in exercise 8.10.py, it requires me to pass a copy of the initial list to the function and print both the appended list, and the original list.

Obviously I have failed to grasp a concept here?

Comment: You get `IndexError: pop from empty list` error because the `while messages:` is always evaluated to `True`.

Comment: `messages` is a copy of `short_texts`. So `short_texts.pop()` doesn't modify `messages`, and the loop is infinite.

Comment: "it requires me to pass a copy of the initial list to the function and print both the appended list, and the original list." Well, which list do you think should get popped - the original, or the copy? Why? Which list's *length should be checked* in order to control the loop - the original, or the copy? Why? Why do you suppose that the book wants you to copy the list? If you remove an element from the copy, do you expect the original's length to change, or vice-versa? Why? Therefore, why would a loop "until the copy is empty", stop when items are removed from the original?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not modifying `messages` in the loop, so the `while messages:` condition never changes, and you have an infinite loop. You should be popping from `messages`, not `short_texts`. Then `messages` will eventually become empty, and the `while messages:` condition will be false and the loop stops.

```
def send_messages(messages):
    while messages:
        popped_st = messages.pop(0)
        print(popped_st)
        sent_messages.append(popped_st)
```

It works when you don't use a slice to call the function, because then `messages` and `short_texts` refer to the same list. In that case, `short_texts.pop(0)` is equivalent to `messages.pop(0)`. The slice makes a copy of the list.